# cannot create monitors.xml which means display settings are lost

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

All around the internet, people complaining that they can't save their multiple-monitor settings are told to select the right settings in the display manager and then click 'apply' which would generate/modify the file `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml`.
However, this file does not exist on my computer (Xubuntu 16.04) and it can also not be created by using the display manager. I have to reconfigure the multi-display settings through the display manager every time i reconnect an external display, which may be multiple times per day.

Does anybody know what's going on and/or know a workaround or alternative to save multi-monitor display settings? Or at least know how to debug this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALTERNATIVE: install `arandr` which allows you to set up your desired configuration with its GUI and then save the corresponding xrandr command in a shell script.

You can then either make a desktop shortcut or define an alias to run that script when your monitor connects (or even write another script that  runs on startup and that detects when your monitor connects to then automatically run the xrandr script).